# How to subset based on if it contains a certain string

Tags: r

I have a data frame, which is basically the Hello list of passengers, with columns of Hello(string), Hello (1st, 2nd or 3rd), Hello, Hello (female or male) and Hello(0 or 1).

Basically, I want to extract the unmarried women from my data frame.

I only want to extract the Hello that contain "Hello". I can't use the `==` operator because it will match it identically. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you all.

I have tried `"Hello` but that did not work.

````
 $ Hello    : Hello w/,..: 22 25 26 27 24 31 45 46 50 54 ...
 $ Hello  : Hello w/ 3 levels "1st","2nd","3rd": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Hello     : He
 - attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Hello int  13 14 15 30 33 36 41 46 47 53 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "13" "14" "15" "30" ...```
````

Comment: Please share a sample of your data with `dput`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for details on how to format your question.

Comment: Please look at my updated post :)

Comment: Please use `dput` not `str`.

Comment: I have over 1000 rows in my dataframe :(

Comment: Please read the link in my first comment. TL DR: Use `dput(head(my_data,12))` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `filter` with `str_detect` to match the substring "Miss" on the 'Name' column.  The `\\b` is appended at the beginning and end to specify the word boundary

```
library(tidyverse)
thetitanic %>%
     filter(str_detect(Name, "\\bMiss\\b"))
```